# Cant get back into windows 10 when deciding to stop arch install

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, arch-linux

So I  followed [this](https://youtu.be/L1B1O0R1IHA) guide for installing arch. This is my first experience with Linux so I don't know what's happening and following along as best as I can. After a reboot stage tho at around 20:40 I decided to stop the whole process because grub wasn't showing windows or arch.

But now when I try to boot back into windows as I did before it just shows the gigabyte logo of my motherboard and I am stuck there.

Please tell me how to cancel the whole process and boot back into windows 10. All mu boot devices are [here](https://ibb.co/g9F2bxD)

Comment: Arch is the absolute worse for a Linux first timer. Not because it isn't good, actually it's a great and venerable distro, but because it requires solid knowledge in order to install and configure. Better choose a typical user-friendly distro like Ubuntu or derivatives. (...)

Comment: (...) And if you're trying to install/manage OSes then you must also have solid knowledge of your firmware (UEFI), know the difference between UEFI mode (preferred) and Legacy whenever applicable, their requirements and boot process. Probably the best you can do now is to boot Windows 10 installation media and repair boot.

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: Best method to fix issue: restore from the *full disk image* you made before attempting such a major change. Alternative, if you *did not make a disk image*: download the Windows 10 ISO from MS (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) using their Media Creation Tool and use it to repair Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

As a general comment, with Windows 10 you don't need to dual-boot in order
to try Linux. You could instead install and use
[Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).
If you want to also run graphical applications, upgrade to Windows 11
and ensure you're using
[WSL version 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/wsl/install).

To restore the Windows 10 startup,
[Run a Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).
You will need a boot USB for Windows 10, or a Recovery media
(if you have created one on your computer or another computer).

If this fails, you will need to do
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).